# DDD, entities, model boundaries

Tags: domain-driven-design

Let's take this simple example. We have two modules. One module is about some questions where we have entity `Question`. This entity require entity from other module, an `User`.

When I need to list all questions (with their authors), my `QuestionRepository` needs to fetch users as well. Questions:

- is it fine that `QuestionRepository` creates the `Question` **and** `Users`?
- or users should be fetched from `UsersRepository`, meaning that `QuestionRepository` is linked to `UserRepository`?
- or users should be fetched from some services (forbidding using repos outside of the modules), but that would give as anemic service methods that are wrapping the repo?

Or something else?

EDIT: please don't write about ORM. That is a tool. I believe this question is about what is actually shared between the modules.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what responsibility you want your repositories to have, there are two approaches:

1. Your repository is responsible for fetching complete and isolated aggregate roots.
   with no navigational properties to other aggregates.
2. Your repository is more like a Query container which contains the queries that your domain needs.

Nr #1 is more isolated and works very well if you don't have an O/R Mapper, you can simply construct your aggregates and return a dead list of aggregates.

Nr #2 is a more pragmatic approach if you do use an O/R Mapper.
This is because 
1) O/R mappers can deal with navigational properties and entire graphs of objects.
2) Some mappers, e.g. Entity Framework will attach entire graphs of new objects when you "Add" to the repository.
e.g. say you create an Order, an OrderDetail and a Product, together and you call `.Add(order)` or `.Save(order)`, EF will attach all three entities. that is, the Product will also be saved if the detail points to it.

So, if you use an O/R mapper, I'd go for approach #2..

And also do note, this as very Little to do with DDD, DDD is about semantics and the model, not about how your infrastructure is designed..

Comment: at one point the model will meet the infrastructure:) I don't want to think here about ORM. That's just a tool. You can't replace such repo with eg nosql repo. Anyway, i think the my question here is about bounded context - what actually is _shared_ between two modules? If my Users are created everywhere, i am loosing single place of creating user. Then again, that is convenient.

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely correct, the thing is though, you can rarely replace the O/RM even with Another O/RM, there are always subtile differences in how things are loaded, persisted, mapped, lazy loaded etc. if you want it completely isolated, you have to avoid any magic feature of the infrastructure. and in such case, #1 is the way to go.

Comment: @lawpert Do you know about Aggregates ? Aggregates typically can't span multiple bounded contexts. Therefore, if `Question` and `User` live in different bounded contexts (and if what you mean by "module" is really a BC), they must belong to different aggregates. Repositories deal with a single Aggregate. Which means, you need a `QuestionRepository` *and* a `UserRepository`.

Answer (score 0):

If Questions entity has a foreign key UserID field & relationship set to Users entity, it is possible to fetch questions along with users.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using EF5 and Linq
you can write linq query to fetch both

Answer (score 0):

If indeed `Question` and `User` are in two different BCs then you may find that `User` in the `Question` BC is actually something else, like `QuestionOwner`.  I am, of course, making up this term for illustrative purposes. :)

An AR should never contain an instance of another AR so irrespective of whether they are in the same BC or not the *contained* AR (`User` in this case) should be represented either by an **Id** or, more appropriately, a VO.  Let's go with a `QuestionOwner` that would contain the `UserId` and `UserName` that is stored in your `Question`.

In this way the `Question` BC consumes some of the `User` BC data and represents the data in a form that has meaning in the `Question` BC.  Remember that since VOs are immutable you would not administer any `QuestionOwner` data in the `Question` BC and even if the corresponding `User` data is changed in the `User` BC you have the added benefit of representing the `User` data as it was when the question was, say, created.  These design decisions are something that you will make depending on your use case.  You may also opt to update the `Question` 'owners' using some eventing framework (service bus) when the user data changes.